Weather on a Hot Saturn
So, out of curiosity and for the purposes of a roleplay universe I am making, I am curious about the weather on a Hot Saturn. This planet, nearly identical in mass, composition and size to Saturn, is 67,000,000 miles from the sun, or 0.72 AU. This sun is also roughly equivalent to our star. I realize this planet probably doesn't technically count as a hot Jupiter/Saturn, at least by Wikipedia's standards, but I am just using the best terminology I have, since because it is significantly closer to the sun, I expect it is significantly hotter. Not sure what temperatures it would be at, but the main question is this;
What would the weather look like on such a planet, since Jupiter and Saturn already have some of the craziest weather in the solar system and some of the biggest storms?
My suspicions would be that the weather is even more extreme. Any ideas how much? Any numbers?
Thanks!

You might want to have the distance in AU as well as miles.

Done! Hope that helps. It is sitting at about the position of Venus btw.

I found two real gas giant exoplanets that orbit K or G type stars at about 0.72 AU: HIP 107773 b and Kepler-108 c. I'm not finding anything about their likely weather patterns yet, but I'll keep looking.

It looks like your planet would technically be classified as a "warm Saturn." Admittedly, the line between “hot” and “warm” wasn’t consistently defined in the sources I found. However, they generally agreed that a gas giant at a distance similar to Venus, specifically between 0.5 and 10 AU, equals a warm Saturn (or Jupiter, but I'll use "Saturn" for consistency). By that definition, however, our Saturn is actually warm, so that means a wide range of potential weather patterns.
There are a few general characteristics for the weather of a warm Saturn. Unlike a hot Saturn, which would be too hot for clouds on the day-side, a warm Saturn could maintain a consistent cloud-cover. The warmer ones could even have hazes of  water, methane, and carbon monoxide. Hydrogen and helium are still going to be the dominant gasses, which is good news for lightning (too much carbon can make sparks harder). A warmer Saturn might even have stronger lightning than our Saturn. The hot Neptune HAT-p-11 b (orbiting at less than 0.05 AU) once produced a radio signal that has been interpreted as an enormous barrage of lightning strikes. While we don't know for certain that was lightning, I would expect that overall a warmer atmosphere is going to mean more energetic convection and therefore more (and more intense) storms.
For more specifics, you'd need to know the average temperature of your planet. I did find a formula for planet temperature. I'm not sure I trust my math skills on the results, though, since I only got 54.25° K (-218.9° C). That seems low since our Saturn is in the neighborhood of 97° K. Saturn’s albedo (a) is 0.34 and the distance (d) is 0.72 AU if anyone with better math skills wants to take a stab at it.
The basic formula: T (temperature) = 279 x (1 – a)1/4 x 1/√d Kelvin
The more complex version is here.
I do want to note that it's quite possible that, even at the same distance as Venus, a warm Saturn may not be as hot as Venus. I couldn't find any estimated temperatures for HIP 107773 b or Kepler-108 c, and CoRoT-9 b at only 0.40 AU is estimated to have a temperature between -20° C and 158° C. I can say that, based on this Astronomy answer, your warm Saturn won’t have a puffy atmosphere. That requires solar irradiation of 105–106 W/m2 and Venus only receives 2601.3 W/m2.
One factor that could really increase the extreme weather for your planet is eccentricity. Many warm Saturns have very circular orbits, which reduces the effect of any seasons they might experience. However, there are also some with extremely eccentric orbits. The most extreme I found is HD 80606 b. Its average orbital distance is 0.46 AU, but it has an eccentricity of 0.93, meaning that it actually swings from as close as 0.03 AU to as far as 0.85 AU. When it swings close, the temperature jumps from 980° F/527° C to 2,240° F/1, 227° C in just 6 hours, unleashing “shock-wave storms” that race around the planet at the speed of sound. These storms probably don’t result in vaporized rock like on some hot Jupiters, but they might reduce the amount of water, methane, and carbon monoxide the planet could sustain.
So if you want really extreme weather, bump up that eccentricity. Otherwise, I'm going to have to go with a vague "like Saturn but more intense" for my prediction of the overall weather patterns for your planet.
